# Large Number of Requests - Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, getaddrinfo

When making a large number of requests in node (using version 6.3.0, but this has also occurred on other versions), I get the error `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND.`  Researching this problem I found the following github issue for older versions of node: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/5488
However, I was unable to find a solution within that thread.

That thread did provide the following example code: https://gist.github.com/eelcocramer/5626801

The gist has three files: `error-case.js`, `fixed-error-case.js`, and `success-case.js`

However, none of the files work  without error for me.

Running `error-case.js` produces the following:

```
...
Request count = 1569
STATUS: 200
Request count = 1570
problem with request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.google.com www.google.com:80
Last successful request count = 1570
problem with request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.google.com www.google.com:80
Last successful request count = 1570
...
```

Yet, when I run `fixed-error-case.js` I get the following:

```
...
Request count = 1562
STATUS: 200
Request count = 1563
problem with request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.google.com www.google.com:80
Last successful request count = 1563
problem with request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.google.com www.google.com:80
Last successful request count = 1563
...
```

And similarly with `success-case.js`

```
Request count = 1563
STATUS: 200
Request count = 1564
problem with request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.google.com www.google.com:80
Last successful request count = 1564
problem with request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.google.com www.google.com:80
Last successful request count = 1564
^C
```

But then, even more notably, if I run it again (after >1 min wait), I get the following:

```
problem with request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.google.com www.google.com:80
Last successful request count = 0
problem with request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.google.com www.google.com:80
Last successful request count = 0
problem with request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.google.com www.google.com:80
Last successful request count = 0
```

So the error seems to persist through multiple runs, interestingly.

Also, since this example code isn't exactly the code I am actually running, I should also note that I have tried using `request-promise` in conjunction with `bluebird's map` function with `concurrency` so that only so many promises are active at a time, but that has not solved the problem either.  (Attempting to run ~300 requests, with concurrency set to 5 still resulted in failure)

Any help/thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I have a similar issue.  It only appears when there are multiple requests as described.

Comment: any updates on this?